# Are there 3 out of 17 students A,B,C such that the hieght,id and phone number of B is in between A and C

Tags: combinatorics

In a clasroom there are 17 students such that no 2 students are at the sam hieght. Are there 3 students A,B,C such that the hieght,id and phone number of B is in between A,C
meaning:

$A_{hieght} > B_{hieght} > C_{hieght}$

$C_{id} > B_{id} > A_{id}$

$C_{phone} > B_{phone} > A_{phone}$

This is a question from our past test that I'm trying to solve but had a hard time
I think it has somthing to do with Erdos–Szekeres theorem but I wasn't able to bulid the right subsequences

My attemp:
We have a sequence of 17 hieghts, so there is a subsequences of 5 hieghts wich are incresing or decreasing (lets say incresing) so they have 5 distinct ids and there is a subsequences of 3 lets say again incresing, so i have
$A_{hieght} < B_{hieght} < C_{hieght}, A_{id} < B_{id} < C_{id}$
First I'm not sure if it's correct, but if it is what do I do next with the phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring too much. Let the $17$ people stand in line according to increasing heights. Then, you say, there is a subsequence of length $5$ where the IDs are increasing or decreasing, and among this subsequence there should be a subsubsequence of length $3$ where the phone numbers are monotone as well.